# Tabular: How to align columns with graphics or enumerate vertically?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

For my thesis I need a two-column layout with labels on the first column and text, tables and graphics in the second. At the moment I use the `tabular` environment like below.

How can I align vertically "Implementation:" to "* ITEM1", "Tabular:" to "A|B" and "Diagram:" to the top of the drawing?

Maybe there is better solution than using `tabular`?

Any hint or recommendation is welcome!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\textbf{ADD A,B,C}                & \textbf{Add A and B and store result in C}     \\
                                  &                                                \\
Addressingmodes:                  & A~~absolut                                     \\
                                  & C~~absolut                                     \\
                                  &                                                \\
Description:                     & $C=A+B$                                         \\
                                  & \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth} 
                                    Add A and B ...
                                    \end{minipage}                                 \\
                                  &                                                \\    
Implementation:                   & \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth} 
                                      \begin{itemize}
                                          \item ITEM1
                                          \item ITEM2
                                      \end{itemize}  
                                    \end{minipage}                                  \\
                                  &                                                 \\
Tabular:                          & \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
                                        \begin{tabular}[t]{c|c}
                                            A & B \\
                                            C & D
                                        \end{tabular}
                                    \end{minipage}                                  \\
Diagram:                          & \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  decoration={
markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {\draw (3pt,2pt) -- (-3pt,-2pt);}
}]

\node (rect) at (4,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=3cm]     {Functional~Unit};

\draw [thick,postaction={decorate}] ($(rect.north west)!0.35!(rect.south west)$) -- ++(-3,0) node[midway,below] {$Operand~A$};

\draw [thick,postaction={decorate}] ($(rect.north west)!0.65!(rect.south west)$) -- ++(-3,0) node[midway,below] {$Operand~B$};

\draw [thick,postaction={decorate}] ($(rect.north east)!0.20!(rect.south east)$) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,below] {$Result$};

\draw [thick,postaction={decorate}] ($(rect.north east)!0.50!(rect.south east)$) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,below] {$PC$};

\draw [thick,postaction={decorate}] ($(rect.north east)!0.80!(rect.south east)$) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,below] {$PSW$};

\draw [thick,postaction={decorate}] ($(rect.north west)!0.50!(rect.north east)$) -- ++(0,1) node[midway,right] {$Enable$};

\end{tikzpicture}

                                    \end{minipage}                                  \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does changing `\begin{minipage}` to `\begin{minipage}[t]` for those two items give you what you want?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "align vertically"? Should the tops of the elements in each column line up, or the middle, or the bottom, or something else?

Comment: I mean the tops of the elments in the columns should line up (top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hoppefuly i understood you correctly:

[image]

i done the following:

- use `tabularx` table environment,
- align first column to the right,  second column is `X` type (using it, the `minipage`s are superfluous),
- for enumerate i use `enumitem` package
- for align `tikzpicture` to the top off cell i add option `baseline=(current bounding box.north)`
- i also give some attention to `tikzpicture` code. now is shorter :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings, positioning}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
\textbf{ADD A,B,C}      & \textbf{Add A and B and store result in C}    \\
Addressingmodes:        & A absolut                                     \\
                        & C absolut                                     \\
Description:            & $C=A+B$                                       \\
                        &  Add A and B \dots                            \\
Implementation:         & \begin{itemize}[nosep,
                                          leftmargin=*,
                                          before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},
                                           after=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}]
                          \item ITEM1
                          \item ITEM2
                          \end{itemize}                                 \\
Tabluar:                & \begin{tabular}[t]{c|c}
                                            A & B \\
                                            C & D
                          \end{tabular}                                 \\
Diagram:                & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),
                            decoration={markings,
                            mark=at position 0.5 with {\draw (3pt,2pt) -- (-3pt,-2pt);}
                                            },
                            line/.style={thick,postaction={decorate}}
                                            ]
    \node (rect) [draw,thick,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=3cm]     {Functional Unit};
    \draw [line] ([yshift= 7mm] rect.west) -- node[below] {\textit{Operand A}} ++(-3,0);
    \draw [line] ([yshift=-7mm] rect.west) -- node[below] {\textit{Operand B}} ++(-3,0);
    \draw [line] ([yshift= 10mm] rect.east) -- node[below] {\textit{Result}} ++(2,0);
    \draw [line] (rect.east) -- node[below] {\textit{PC}} ++(2,0) ;
    \draw [line] ([yshift=-10mm] rect.east) -- node[below] {\textit{PSW}} ++(2,0);
    \draw [line] (rect.north) -- node[right] {\textit{Enable}} ++(0,1);
                        \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```